# Detect if word is spelled out or said, DialogFlow/Actions-on-Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, voice

I'm creating an action for google assistant/ home and its crucial I be able to tell the difference between a user spelling out something or simply saying that thing.

Comment: Alright who downvoted this? This is a legitimate question

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether the user input was speech or text by checking the [InputType](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/InputType)in the [request](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#RawInput)

If you are using the Actions on Google Node.js client library for your fulfillment, you can access this value through [conv.input.type](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.input.html#type)

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant, I was talking about if it's possible to detect if a user says a word, like 'cat', or says it letter by letter, like 'c a t', because sometimes google auto changes both of those inputs to 'cat'